# Pandas How to sum month value with each id

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like this.

```
id           date     amount
2        2018-04-03    10
2        2018-04-22    20     
3        2018-01-21    20
4        2018-03-13    10 
4        2018-04-19    30
```

I want to sum amount of each month and each id. So the result will be like this. The month not same for in each id.

```
id           date     amount
2          2018-04    30
3          2018-01    20
4          2018-03    10 
4          2018-04    30
```

I test by this code.

```
df['amount'].groupby(df['date'].dt.to_period('M')).sum()
```

The result is.

```
pos_dt
2018-04   60
2018-01   20
2018-03   10
```

It's not group by separate with id. How to fix it?

Comment: You `.groupby(['id', df['date'].dt.to_period('M')])`?

Comment: df.groupby(df.date.dt.month)['amount'].sum()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group *both* by the `id` and the month, so you can calculate this with:

```
df.groupby(['id', df['date'].dt.to_period('M')]).sum()
```

For example:

```
>>> df.groupby(['id', df['date'].dt.to_period('M')]).sum()
            amount
id date           
2  2018-04      30
3  2018-01      20
4  2018-03      10
   2018-04      30
```